# Hide Django ClearableFileInput checkbox

Tags: django, django-forms

How to hide the check-box in django `ClearableFileInput`.
I have a form which I what to hide the check-box so that if you want to change you have to upload a new one as it is a required field.

Comment: Is the field *required* or not null? Show us some code.

Comment: yes its a required field

Comment: Why not use a simple `FileInput`?

Answer (score 1):

If the form uses a **ImageField** then use the **FileInput** widget instead of the **ClearableFileInput**

```
class Meta:
    widgets = {
        'field_name': forms.FileInput,
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, you can use FileInput, but you're going to hide the checkbox and "Currently: path_to_file" both.

One solution to hide just the checkbox is to subclass ClearableFileInput widget, this way:

```
#widgets.py
from django.forms.widgets import FileInput
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class NotClearableFileInput(FileInput):
    initial_text = ugettext_lazy('Currently')
    input_text = ugettext_lazy('Change')

    template_with_initial = '%(initial_text)s: %(initial)s <br />%(input_text)s: %(input)s'

    url_markup_template = '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>'

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        substitutions = {
            'initial_text': self.initial_text,
            'input_text': self.input_text,
        }
        template = '%(input)s'
        substitutions['input'] = super(NotClearableFileInput, self).render(name, value, attrs)

        if value and hasattr(value, "url"):
            template = self.template_with_initial
            substitutions['initial'] = format_html(self.url_markup_template,
                                               value.url,
                                               force_text(value))

        return mark_safe(template % substitutions)
```

Now you can use this widget in the form:

```
    widgets = {
        'field_name': widgets.NotClearableFileInput,
    }
```

You'll have this result:

[image: result]

Reference: [widgets.py from django repository](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py)

Answer (score 0):

If the FileInput is `required`, then the checkbox is not displayed. `required` means that the field is a mandatory field of the model.

The following is the code snippet which you can find the in the template of the ClearableFileInput.

```
{% if not widget.required %}
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ widget.checkbox_name }}" id="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}"{% if widget.attrs.disabled %} disabled{% endif %}>
<label for="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}">{{ widget.clear_checkbox_label }}</label>
{% endif %}
```

Notice the `if not widget.required` which checks if the file input is mandatory.